# How to have a remote connection with postgres?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, remote-access

I have a postgres database on a Linux  computer and I want to access it from two other computer, a mac and a windows,I search through stackoverflow and some tutorials around the web but all of them(of what I found) show [how to allow a remote connection to database.](https://bosnadev.com/2015/12/15/allow-remote-connections-postgresql-database-server/)

I done what allow a remote connection but I don't know how should I connect to my database, assume I want to connect from a python script using sqlalchemy. 
I appreciate your help if you tell me how can I access the database using terminal and cmd in addition to the way I have access from sqlalchemy.

I set `listen_addresses='*'` in `postgresql.conf` and add `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` to the last line of `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have made the `postgres` db to accessed from outside.

Also I assume, you already have user and full privileged database name created on `postgress` db.

Therefore if db has user `remote` with password `remote` and have full permission on db `mydb` then using below command on remote computer you can gain access to.

Make sure remote computer has postgresql server/client installed too

```
psql -Uremote -h <remote-ip-address> -d my_db -Wremote
```

Gaining accessed using SqlAlchemy you can refer @Kalyan Answers

Comment: I'm not sure that our assumption about accessing from outside is true, but before to investigate that, how can I find out my remote ip address, I try to use ifconfig and find what starts with 192.168.*.*  if that is the way I should find remote-ip I think db is not allowed to access from outside.

Comment: Yes that's right. ifconfig will show the correct IP. You can look at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/comment-page-1/ to config remote access

Answer (score -1):

Requirements:
   1. SQLAlchemy 
   2. psycopg2

use pip to install the above packages.

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
pip install psycopg2
```

An example of a `SQLAlchemy` connection string that uses `psycopg2` (you may use python cmd for quick test):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine=create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name')
```